# Strange VS 2015 behavior when Entity Framework NuGet package is installed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I'm using **VS 2015** and developing a **Universal Windows 10 app**. I have created a "Class library (Universal Windows)" to act as my persistence layer.
 The problem is that when I download Entity Framework NuGet package, I'm missing the namespace for: **System.Data.Entity** . So basically I'm not able to derive from DbContext to create my DB model. 
The Entity Framework package shows up in "References" section of the project. I have tried cleaning up everything and rebuilding the solution again but still VS can't find this namespace. 
I have also Unity (IoC) NuGet package installed and it's working perfectly, the problem seems to be only with EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Entity Framework 6.x is not compatible with WinRT thus it cannot be used in Universal Apps.

The next release, Entity Framework 7, will have have this fixed.